# How do I retrieve specific objects from a model related to another model through a foreignkey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am building a django app which basically shows newsfeeds (a thematic + a series of news items). Thematics and items are manually entered in the DB through two models.

These two models: a 'Feed' model, which describes a newsfeed thematic and a 'Feed_element' model, which describes news items which enter under a specific thematic (a 'feed'). The Feed_element is related to the Feed model through a Foreignkey.

I'd like to get the feeds that respond to a criteria (front_feed = True, see attached models code) and the accompanying feed_elements, which I thought I could wove together in the view with a select_related(). But this doesn't work.

I cannot figure the view syntax.

MODELS

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Feed(models.Model):
feed_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default = "country_name")
feed_current = models.TextField(max_length = 10000, default = "feed_current")
feed_country = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default = "feed_country")
feed_front = models.BooleanField(default = False)

def __str__(self):
return self.feed_name


class Feed_element(models.Model):
parent_feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete = models.CASCADE,    related_name = "elements")
element_date = models.DateField()
element_short = models.TextField(max_length = 200, default = "element_short")
element_long = models.TextField(max_length = 200, default = "element_long")

def __str__(self):
return self.element_short
```

VIEWS

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect

from .models import Feed, Feed_element

def index(request, posted = None):


return render(request, 'trails/index.html', { 'feeds' :     Feed.objects.filter(feed_front = True),
'elements' :     Feed_element.objects.select_related('parent_feed').all()
}
)
```

TEMPLATE

```
{% if feeds %}
    {% for feed in feeds %}
       <div class = "column">
    <h2 align="center" font-weight: normal> FEED: {{ feed.feed_name }}</h2>
    {% for element in elements %}
    <li>
    <a>{{ elements.element_short }} <br> | </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

I expect to get a column with the feed's name on top and a list of feed's elements following under. Instead, what I get is:

1) a list of bullet points (the list of elements), with the total number of elements (how many feed elements I've entered the DB) and not the specific feed's foreignkey-related elements,

2)but blank (the text doesn't appear)

Comment: I apologize for the awful formatting of my question! I'm fairly new at both Django AND Stackoverflow! I will try to straighten it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking it. `Feed` instances will have a manager that lets you fetch their associated elements - see the [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) docs. In this case, you've specified the `related_name` on the fk, so that's the name of the manager.

In your view, you don't need to explicitly load the elements - just set the feeds you want and pass the feeds into the template context. Then in the template, access the `elements` manager, something like:

```
{% for element in feed.elements.all %}
```

Note that this isn't using `select_related`. That's for optimizing queries from many-to-one or one-to-one relationships, so it'd help if you had a particular feed element you wanted to fetch and not have to hit the database again to get its related `feed`. It doesn't cover one-to-many relationships such as you have from feed to feed element. You could try using `prefetch_related` to avoid the repeated database queries to get the related `feed_elements` - something like:

```
Feed.objects().filter(feed_front=True).prefetch_related('elements')
```

That's not quite as helpful as `select_related`, because it still has to make multiple db queries, but it does the grouping for you - again, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) have details.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much for helping me! My app now shows me the proper number of elements for each feed.... Unfortunately, the text still doesn't appear. Only the bullet points. Do you think it is related?

Comment: Your example template is trying to reference `elements`, which shouldn't even be in your context anymore - probably something like just `<a>{{ element }} <br> | </a>` would be a starting point (using your defined `__str__` method to turn the element into displayable text).

Comment: I was replying at the same time you posted your answer. I've managed to fix that last glitch. Once again thank you for pulling me out of the ditch!

Comment: Jumping ahead a little, you might want something like `{% if not forloop.last %} <br> | {% endif %}</a>` to hide your `|` divider after the last item. If that's what you want, mostly I'm just pointing out the existence of the `forloop` template variables.